# Licensing system for client side code web application

Tags: encryption, cryptography, javascript, rsa, client-side

I have a client-side web application running on SharePoint Site Collection, each site collection has it's own unique id. I want to use a licensing process to lock the app to a site collection.

This is the challenge-response process I'm trying to implement:

- User prompted to generate `challenge code`
- `challenge code` is `site_collection_id` processed through some function
- User emails me `challenge code`
- I encrypt/hash `challenge code` with **someting** (RSA private key?)
- The encrypted result is considered the `license key` which I send to user
- User saves `license key` into the application

Validation Process:

- On app load, retrieve `license key`
- Decrypt/un-hash `license key` using **something** (RSA public key?)
- The result is the `challenge code` the user had sent before
- Compare the `challenge code` you've generated from the `license` to the one you'd get from the site to determine if they match

Does this make sense? The one thing I'm not sure about is the public/private key stuff and if there's a way to do this in JavaScript. From what I've read, I can't use RSA securely to encrypt with private key and decrypt with public. It's normally the opposite. So I'm looking for alternatives

Just to be clear, I need to store something in the application script that I can use to decrpyt the license but I'd be encrypting the challenge code either on a different site or server side

---

I know it's impossible to 100% secure client-side applications. I'm just looking for something to prevent someone from **easily** distributing the application

Answer (score 2):

Your scheme is pretty close, i'd say. RSA in JavaScript is a pain in the ass, so look for a library that does it for you. This is my suggestion for your final scheme:

1. Client sends you the site id *i*
2. You sign that id with your private key *p*: *S = RSA-SIGN(i, p) = i^d mod n*
3. You send *S* back to the client in a file or in an e-mail
4. Client stores the license file
5. When the web app loads, download the file (*S'*) and your public key *o* and do the math: *S'' = RSA-VERIFY(S', o) = S'^e mod n*. If *S'' = S'*, the license is ok.

The RSA formulas in here are Textbook-RSA and cryptographically insecure. One might recover the private key. So make sure to use proper padding and hashing (keyword: PKCS7)

P.S.: As the TO said, this is not 100% secure. It cannot be since client-side code can be fully tampered with easily.

P.S.S.: I think an online form for steps 1 through 3 would be much better usability-wise than emailing that stuff around.

Comment: yea eventually I would create an activation site where it could all be automated. So client would signup with purchase number or something, paste in their challenge code or site_id (I prefer using a challenge code instead of their site id for security) then I'd generate a license automatically for them on that activation site and they'd just input that into the app. But that's way in the future.

Comment: Would this only work with RSA? I found this library [cryptopjs](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) that has various other encryption options but I'm not sure if they'd fit

Comment: This works with any public-key algorithm that supports signatures, e.g. ECC or ElGamal.

Comment: Okay well I found (this)[https://github.com/wwwtyro/cryptico] library which seems pretty simple (this stuff is really complex). It seems to support public-key algorithm like you mentioned unlike what the previous one I linked. From their example, I should be able to generate a public key, store it in the application permanently and use that to decrypt the response. Anyways, I'll have to play around with it more and see.